# Android XML парсер

Tags: xml, android, парсер

Есть код:

```
    XmlPullParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.xmlfile);
    while (parser.getEventType()!= XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG
            && parser.getName().equals("contact")) {
        list.add(parser.getAttributeValue(0) + " "
                + parser.getAttributeValue(1) + "\n"
                + parser.getAttributeValue(2));
    }
    parser.next();
}
```

Xml файл указывается в локальной папке, как подгружать файл с сайта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то так:

```
    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true); //если надо
    XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
    URL input = new URL(url); //url удаленного документа
    xpp.setInput(input.openStream(), null);
    //далее как обычно
```

Не забудьте добавить пермишен на доступ к сети в манифесте